# How to check one string has comma separated value using PHP

Tags: php

I need one help.I need to check two type of string value using PHP. I am explaining one example below.

suppose one variable

```
$sup_id='4' //(datatype-varchar)

$sup_id='4,5,6' //(datatype-varchar)
```

in above example i have different value in same variable name.Here how can i check that the same variable has one value or different with comma(`,`) separated.Please help me.

Comment: what if  `$sup_id='4,'` then what should be output  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be easily done by [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos($sup_id, ',') !== false) {
  echo "There's a comma in the string...!!!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
$str = '4,5,6';

$exploded = explode(',', $str);

if (sizeof($exploded) > 1) {
  echo 'It is split.';
else {
  echo 'Its not.';
}
```

What you're doing is, you are splitting the string into an array based on the `,` delimiter. So if a `,` exists, the array will have more than 1 value.

Comment: It is the `'It's not.';` sentence, he closed the string and kept writting more letters

Comment: Shouldn't it be checking if the `sizeof($exploded) > 1`? It's counting the separated elements, not the commas... (so no commas will have 1 value)